# Failed to Download Package Files

Tags: audacity

I have been trying to update my system in order to install Audacity. I got most of the updates to work but not the security updates for some reason. Now every time i try and download audacity from the software centre it comes up with the message 'Failed to download package files: Check internet connection.'
There does not appear to be anything amiss with the net so i'm at a loss.

Also I'm not very good with comp/tech issues so please respond with advice that is a step-by-step as possible.

I'm very happy with Ubuntu system overall but lack the tech ability when it goes wrong. 
Thank you.

Comment: I have managed to download the Files for Audacity but can not seam to make the program install. Again some detailed advice on how to make these install and run would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

- In **Update Manager** open **Settings...** which opens **Software Sources** from which could can check (and alter) **Download from:** and select a different download-mirror which might help to get past that error message.
- Further, you might just want to **wait a day or two** (if it's not urgent) and hope the error'll *just go away by itself* (ie, the "hang" in the download-server to be resolved).
- Finally, I'm confused by you writing that you "downloaded the Files for Audacity". Why would you do that? I mean, *manually*? Just open the **Ubuntu Software Center**, search for/select **Audacity**, click install and be done with it... no?